# Define or not wp_ajax_nopriv

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a plugin for WP that use AJAX functionality. I define 'wp_ajax_my_action' and it works good. Should I handle 'wp_ajax_nopriv' if I do not need access for non 'authenticated' users. This AJAX should work only in the admin side.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the AJAX action is only necessary for logged in users then you don't need the `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Its no point using `wp_ajax_nopriv` because non-privileged users are already far from reach of that code. `wp_ajax_nopriv` is intended for front side of the site.